# Only give method block and yield if block_given?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a basic td_tag helper that wraps the content_tag method in application_helper.rb

```
def td_tag(*args)
  if block_given?
    content_tag(:td, *args) do
      yield
    end
  else
    content_tag(:td ,*args)
  end
end
```

What is the ruby-way of making this code shorter?

This example works, in a way, but it doesn't seem nessesary to call the same function with same parameters, just with and without a block?

By appending just *block_given?* to the *yield* row inside the block doesn't work, since then I have already given the next function a block to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accept the block as an argument and just pass it through. No need to use `block_given?`.

This is functionally identical to your code:

```
def td_tag(*args, &block)
  content_tag(:td, *args, &block)
end
```

It's completely safe; if you do not give the method a block, `block` will be `nil` and `block_given?` inside `content_tag` will be false.